# How to set two different themes on one WordPress? (Desktop vs. Mobile)

Tags: themes, css

I created two WordPress themes.

First for the Desktop and second for tablet/mobile. I want to set on one URL. When the website opens, the theme should change automatically based on resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To employ two entirely separate themes is a suboptimal architectural approach.
Themes are activated site-wide/globally and not on a per-user basis. You don't want to change the current theme constantly.

While I personally really dislike this option, WordPress ships with a function that [sniffs the UA-String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_sniffing), [`wp_is_mobile`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile).
This function can be employed to either output alternative markup and/or load an alternative stylesheet (from within the same theme).

Or - and this is my personal choice - familiarize yourself with [CSS3 mediaqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Answer (score 0):

For simple, you may try this plugin,
http://wordpress.org/plugins/device-theme-switcher/

See this thres also,
[How to detect mobile devices and present them a specific theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/how-to-detect-mobile-devices-and-present-them-a-specific-theme)

for more customization have to play with code to manipulate the options table meta values for 'stylesheet', 'template'.