# change theme when on mobile and also on Ipad portrait view

Tags: mobile, switch-theme

I am familiar with responsive websites and totally prefer it over working with different mobile versions, however, I have a case where there is a site that is alreay built and it is not responsive and wasn't even built for mobile view unfortunately.
my challenge is to make it compatible with mobile so I decided to build a new theme that is targeted for mobile so when viewers are viewing the site on mobile they will be redirected to another theme.

in order to achive that I am working with 
[Any Mobile Theme Switcher](http://wordpress.org/plugins/any-mobile-theme-switcher/)

Now, that works fine but thats not the end of the story.
I want that theme to also appear on ipad portrait orientation.
I dont need landscape because I wrote media queries for that but for portrait view I would like to display the new mobile theme that I am building.

anyone has an idea how to do it?

Thanks
Gil

Comment: The problem is that the orientation is something you only know once the page is already loaded. So the only way to change the theme then is to reload the whole page with another theme. So every time the user turns its device you would need to reload the page. This doesn't feel like a good idea.

Comment: This [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115411/how-to-set-two-different-themes-on-one-wordpress-desktop-vs-mobile) might help