# Show child theme for users on specific IP

Tags: filters, templates, switch-theme

I have some users coming in from a fixed IP range on a very slow connection (256kbps) so want to server them a child theme that has a lot of the bandwidth intensive features removed. For ease of management/maintanability a child theme is preferred to a seperate theme.

I have setup a plugin so I can detect IP, and trigger:

```
add_action('setup_theme', 'switch_user_theme');
function switch_user_theme() {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if ( $ip == 'x.x.x.x' ) {
         $user_theme = 'baspresslite';
         add_filter( 'template', create_function( '$t', 'return "' . $user_theme . '";' ) );
         add_filter( 'stylesheet', create_function( '$s', 'return "' . $user_theme . '";' ) );
    }
}
```

This works fine for switching users to a seperate theme, but **not to a child theme** as a child theme needs to also call files from the parent theme - it seems these filters basically do a rewrite on all requests.

How can this be achieved? Are there alternative filters / actions to hook in to? Or maybe a rewrite action in .htaccess that says if you try to load a file and it isn't found then try this alternative path replacing the child theme name with the parent theme (potential redirect loop here though)?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/how-to-detect-mobile-devices-and-present-them-a-specific-theme

Comment: @kraftner - thanks, I didn't know about those other filters. I'll give them a go.